# .htaccess security headers for IONOS

Tags: htaccess, security, http-headers, mod-security

I need to implement security headers for a website hosted by IONOS. I've used the following code, which works on sites hosted elsewhere, but not here.

```sh
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
```

Does anyone have experience implementing security headers in this way for IONOS, or does it need to be done on the server?

Comment: When it doesn't work, do you get an error, or do the headers not get set, or something else?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `IfModule` check to see if the headers module is missing?

Comment: .htaccess is "on the server," or did you mean that it might have be done in the main server configuration files?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I run it through securityheaders.com - that just tells me the headers are missing. If I remove IfModule I get a server error - so does this mean mod_headers is not enabled? By on the server - I mean configured in Apache rather than htaccess. I'm guessing from your reply that the code is sound, so I just need to speak to the hosts. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to consult the `error_log` file to diagnose the server error.  It likely means that `mod_headers` is not available, but check the error log to be sure.

Comment: @Andrew did you check the logs and work things out on the security headers? Dealing with the same issue. Did add headers in .htaccess, nothing changed.  They do run mod_headers https://www.ionos.com/help/hosting/htaccess/available-apache-modules/?source=helpandlearn so this should work...

Comment: @rhand - I had to get IONOS to do the work for a fee (which the client paid luckily). I don't know what they did, but I'm guessing it was a server configuration.